# Pass value to another variable inside a promise doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a component in my application using **Vue.js** and **Firebase** and in the `created()` lifecycle, i'm getting an **id** that I saved in LocalStorage to use in a promise to [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) data in my **firestore** database. The get() data filter by the **id** works fine but inside the promise i want to pass the value that i got to another variable, but the value changes with `NAN` in some fields, you could see in the two console.log() below. I just want to keep the same value `doc.data.bdCalculo`  in variable `self.bdCalculo` (needed to use `self` because the `this` doesn't work):

```
created: function(){
                // get the id in localstorage
                let id_di = localStorage.getItem('id_di');
                let self = this
                
                var docRef = db.collection("dis").doc(id_di);

                docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                       var  diFinal = doc.data();

                console.log("Data that comes from Firestore:", doc.data().bdCalculo);

   // The data in firestore comes with some arrays called Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4 and bdCalculo
                 self.step1 = diFinal.Step1;
                 self.step2 = diFinal.Step2;
                 self.step3 = diFinal.Step3;
                 self.step4 = diFinal.Step4;
                 self.bdCalculo = diFinal.bdCalculo; 
                 console.log("Data after pass the value to self.bdCalculo", self.bdCalculo);
               
                
                // pass the valeu of self.bdCalculo to a method in vue.js
                 self.calcCustoFob(self.bdCalculo);
           
                } else {
                console.log("No such document!");
                }
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                });
            },
```

The data in the **first** `console.log` is:

[image]

The data after pass the value to `self.bdCalculo` in the second `console.log()`:
[image]

Comment: It probably works fine, but you're calling `doc.data()` twice and each returns different results.

Comment: @Ouroborus why would that happen? .data would only return different values if those values changed in the database

Comment: Why are you logging `diFinal.bdCalculo` when you are interested in `self.bdCalculo`?

Comment: @JulianKleine I edited, was loggin self.bdCalculo

Comment: @Ouroborus where i'm calling `doc.data()` twice?

Comment: Once when you set `diFinal` and once in the first `console.log()`. I don't know why it would be different. However, `.data().bdCalculo` seems to return an array with two items, with the array's first item containing elements that match up with the `NaN` entries in the array's second item. That's unlikely to be a coincidence.

Comment: @Ouroborus I want to keep the same value in doc.data.bdCalculo and self.bdCalculo and i dont know WHY in second console.log the variable CHANGES the value because i didnt change the doc.data.bdCalculo.

Comment: @Ouroborus any idea whats wrong?

Comment: No idea. All I can tell you is that, for some reason, the data doesn't appear to be ready in the first call to `doc.data()` but is ready in the second call. You might try `doc.get("bdCalculo")` instead.

Comment: @Ouroborus ´do.get("bdCalculo")´ where? i don't know why the array change de values by himself.